# How to run python with mod_wsgi apache on windows

Tags: python, apache

I'm having a difficult time trying to set up the mod_wsgi on Apache, is there any dummy tutorial out there that shows how to set this step by step?

Answer (score 1):

Check if this one can help you:
https://beamtic.com/installing-mod-wsgi-apache-windows

Comment: Thanks, and where I can find the mod_wsgi.so because on google is no longer available and on GitHub the repository doesn't really explain how to build the file